# How java objects uses memory?

Tags: java, oop, memory, memory-management

I'm just starting with programming and I don't know much about computers, like memory, cpus the internal stuff.

Ok the basics that i know!

In the java documentation:

- byte   = 8 bits
- short  = 16 bits
- int    = 32 bits
- long   = 64 bits
- float  = 32 bits
- double = 64 bits
- char   = 16 bits

My class:

```
public classFoo{
    int a;
    int b;
    long c;
    long d;
}
```

This code allocates 256 bits in memory or it needs more?

Methods consume memory?

if I have 10 Foo objects they will consume 2560 bytes in memory?

And how about Strings and booleans, how the memory is managed for it?

What other things have impact in memory in a object?

Comment: So many that you shouldn't be worried about it if you're just starting to program.

Answer (score 0):

**It's not about how many objects, but actually size of objects created.**
You assign some memory to Java program or `JVM`, it utilizes that memory and allocates objects.

Few object might take small memory, while few can take more.

It depends on server machine to machine, how much space is allocated to JVM etc.

Also, it does depends upon **`GC`**, whenever memory consumption is high, `JVM` runs `GC` and free up the memory.

One full memory is exhausted, JVM complains and throws [OutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)

A simple Java program can throw OOM error

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long[] l = new long[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
}
```

**Output**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
```

The concept is big, but you are totally into wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of the objects u are creating.. According to the memory allocated by the user or programmer JVM uses that memory for allocating objects..
[Java](http://www.javaprepare.com/java-tutorial/)